# Ant property not evaluated correctly?

Tags: ant, properties

I am using a custom ant buildscript for my Android app.

I have a property `${distributionTarget}` that is evaluated to for example `Android_Market`.
However, in some methods, I don't get the output of `app-Android_Market-release.apk` but I get `app-${distributionTarget}-release.apk`.

I am positive the property has been set correctly, since earlier in the build-stage I have a `echo` method, that does shows the value of the property correctly.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the property was initialized earlier on with no value. Refactoring the build-script to init the properties later made it work.